# SQL No Suitable Driver Found when using dist

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc

I've got a piece of software I'm developing that connects to an MS SQL Database

So far in NetBeans it is working great, however when trying to use the jar version in the dist folder that Netbeans creates, I'm getting the "No Suitable Driver Found" error

It's really puzzling as I've tried everything that I can find about the error online such as:

- Clean & Build (lots of times)
- Adding the JDBC4.jar directory to the Windows CLASSPATH
- Registering the Driver with; Class.forname(...)
- Putting the file reference in the build.xml

and anything else I could find.

I'm using the newest stable JRE, JDK and Netbeans plus the JDBC 4.0 from Microsoft.

I don't know what code I'd need to include for people to help so let me know and I'll provide anything you need to see.

EDIT:

My URL I'm using to connect is: "`jdbc:sqlserver://Room-PC\\sqlexpress`" This works when running from NetBeans but not when I run the jar file in the dist folder.

2nd Edit:

This is the code used to load and first connect to the database. It is in a separate class called DatabaseHandler. This imports java.sql.*; and this connection code is called from the constructor of the class.

As I say it works perfectly when used from the netbeans IDE but not from double clicking the jar file or from command line.

```
username = "adam";
password = "*****"

try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                 "jdbc:sqlserver://Room-PC\\sqlexpress", username, password);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e + "\n");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.out.println("OOPS CLASS NOT FOUND");
        }
```

My Windows CLASSPATH variable is:

".;C:\JDBC\sqljdbc_3.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar" (without quotes)

And I've tried running the program using the command that Luiggi posted but that didn't change anything

So basically I'm just running using java -jar myJar.jar (without -jar it give no main class found)

Thanks for all the help so far guys, I'm racking my brains out with this one!

Comment: How did you added the driver into your project?

Comment: I added it in properties->libraries->compile & run. In NetBeans

Comment: properties->libraries->compile->add jar/Folder?

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant :)

Comment: @Dmytro is that not for a mySQL database not a microsoft one?

Comment: That is for *any* library that your application needs - including JDBC drivers. It has nothing to do with the actual DBMS (or with whatever the library does)

Comment: "*No Suitable Driver Found*" indicates that your JDBC connection **URL** is wrong. There is nothing wrong with your library setup. Please post the actual URL you are using (and you don't need `Class.forName()` - nowadays JDBC drivers register themselves without that. If your classpath was wrong you'd get a `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've added it to the original post. I just don't understand why it works when running from netbeans if the url is wrong

Comment: Sorry @a_horse_with_no_name, just noticed your changes. However the connection url is still the same as what it is in my project but copied with only one backslash. Therefore I can still connect when running from NetBeans but not from the dist folder! :/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You also get that error if the class wasn't loaded. I suspect the op catched all exceptions around `Class.forName` and ignored them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Luiggi Mendoza Thank you for the Answer. It worked!

All I needed to do was add "/lib.sqljdbc4.jar" to the CLASSPATH heading in the manifest file

So:

```
Class-Path: resources/ lib/sqljdbc4.jar
```

That was literally all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The classpath must be set for both compilation and execution time. Currently, you're only doing it for compile time but not for runtime.

Setting the library in the classpath for runtime depends on the kind of project:

- A standalone application: you need to set the external libraries in `-classpath` properties. In a command line, this would be:

  ```
  $ java -classpath "./lib/*;." yourJar.jar
  ```

  Where `lib` is a folder where all your external libraries are placed and `yourJar.jar` is your Java standalone application in the root of the folder. This would be somewhat like this:

  ```
  - some_folder
    + yourJar.jar
    - lib
      + thirdPartyLib1.jar
      + thirdPartyLib2.jar
      + (and on...)
  ```

  Note that Netbeans will only create and write `yourJar.jar` in `dist` folder. It **will not** include any third party library there.
- Web application: put all your third party libraries into WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Hi Luiggi, I tried the command above and it unfortunately gave me the same error. There is a lib folder in the same directory as the main jar file but it is still not working :/

Comment: It's now giving a "fatal exception occured: cannot create virtual machine" error, not sure why as the cmd looks like it should work. Once again thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: Ok, opened a new command prompt and its now just giving the no suitable driver found error again. Will the same command work on a Windows environment as that looks like it's written for linux?

Comment: @ajp8868 fixed the command one more time after further testing.

Comment: Still the same "Driver not found" Error :/ I don't understand why Microsoft's instructions don't work properly. Could it possibly be because I'm using sqljdbc4?

Comment: Oh yeah, my Netbeans does create a lib folder in the dist folder which includes all of the 3rd party jar's

Comment: @ajp8868 The error simply means that either the driver is not on the classpath (and no the windows `CLASSPATH` variable is ignored for almost all application), or you used the wrong URL. In the first case the driver is not even present, in the second case the driver thinks you want to use a different driver. You really need to show **your code** and **the commandline** you use to start the app.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've added the code to the post, if there's any more that you need let me know

Comment: @ajp8868 you also have to add a MANIFEST.MF file where you will include the name of the entry point for your jar.